# How to update the field of django model from the existing field on the Fly

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

How to update the field of django model by `taking/extracting values or filtering values` from existing field of same object?

I have the following model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField,ArrayField

class MyUrlModel(models.Model):
    urls_json_data = JSONField(blank=True,null=True,default=dict)
    urls_list = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),blank=True,null=True,default=list)
```

field `urls_json_data` has the following data in json:

```
[{"protocol":"http","hostname":"google.com","port":80"},{"protocol":"https","hostname":"apple.com","port":443"}]
```

Here, i would like to fetch the structures from `urls_json_data` and make it into url structure like following and save them under `urls_list` which is ArrayField.

```
urls_list=['http://google.com:80','https://apple.com:443']
```

So whenever `urls_json_data` get's updated, I want to fetch the URLs from it and save it under `urls_list` on the fly. What is the best approach to do it, is it by signals or by altering save method?

```
urls_list = []
for each_data in urls_json_data:
  url = each_data['protocol']+each_data['hostname']+each_data['port']
  urls_list.append(url)
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you have to save the json first? Can you not convert the json into URLs before saving?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, I would like to know if there are any other workarounds to do it on the fly when `urls_json_data` field gets updated/created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, whenever you find yourself in a situation that one field depends on the value of another field, most of the time it's a better idea to make the dependent field an attribute e.g. using the `property` descriptor.

In your case, you *should* make `urls_list` a `property`:

```
class MyUrlModel(models.Model):
    urls_json_data = JSONField(blank=True,null=True,default=dict)

    @property
    def urls_list(self):
        # Parse `self.urls_json_data` and return
```

Now from any instance of the model, you can refer to the value by `<instance>.urls_list`.

If you think `urls_list` is computationally expensive, then you can make it a method e.g. `get_urls_list` instead to make sure the users do not *think* of `urls_list` like a *cheap* field access.

---

If you insist on using `urls_list` as a field that depends on the current value of `urls_json_data`, you can override `save` method of the model and do the operations there before saving the field e.g.:

```
class MyUrlModel(models.Model):
    urls_json_data = JSONField()
    urls_list = ArrayField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # `self.get_from_urls_json_field()` is a placeholder
        # for the actual operations to be done
        self.urls_list = self.get_from_urls_json_field()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That's a nice decorator & a good way, but the little disadvantage is when we have large `urls_json_data` & every time I call that object it will load the property, is there any way to save it in a field? so that it can it the fast way.

Comment: is it possible to update the field of other model field instead of the same model field?

Comment: @ArbazzHussain Yes, you need to get the object(s) from that model (see `Queryset.get`/`QuerySet.filter`), and do the update.

Answer (score 1):

You may not even need to store the data, you can add a property that will return the URLs dynamically

```
class MyUrlModel(models.Model):
    urls_json_data = JSONField(blank=True,null=True,default=dict)

    @property
    def urls_list(self):
        return ['{protocol}{hostname}{port}'.format(**url) for url in self.urls_json_data]
```